# CSS Selector nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am facing issues writing a slightly complex CSS selector.

I want to select a div with "class" containing `'btn-group'`, but not `'open'`

So I have something like;

```
div[class*='btn-group']:not([class='open'])
```

Now the issue is that there are around 5-6 elements that match the above condition. But I want to select the first out of that. How do I do the same?

Would prefer doing using `nth-child`..

Answer (score 6):

What about: `div[class*='btn-group']:not(.open):first-of-type`?

**[Edit]:** This trick does not work if you have `<div class="btn-group open"></div>` as the first child... (as explained by @Jukka below) a JS-based trick will work, tho:

```
$("div[class*='btn-group']").not(".open").first()
    .css({...});

    // OR add a class
    // .addClass("class");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/LdDCH/

Comment: Whether it works depends on context, but generally it doesn’t, because `:first-of-type` only tests whether the element is the first `div` child of its parent.

Comment: True enough — therefore I've added the jQuery alternative.

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
div [class*='btn-group']:not([class='open']):nth-child(1) {
    color:Red;
}
```

Using this you can select first child

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/47UMx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. CSS selectors can’t be used that way. But if you provide a more specific HTML context (including containers for the `div` elements and a description of a pattern that the markup follows), there might be a way that works under some assumptions.

In particular, `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type` only test whether the element is the *n*th child, or the *n*th child of its kind, of its parent. It does *not* take e.g. classes into account; the is no “nth of a class” selector.